# Rest Starter Kit in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: rest, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to use the Rest Starter Kit in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2?
I installed the starter kit but cannot see the templates anywhere.

Thxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the link

[Visual Studio Templates Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B1%5D.Value=WCF%20REST%20Service&f%5B0%5D.Value=templates&f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory)

Answer (score 1):

The Release Notes of the REST Starter Kit only shows that it only support Visual Studio 2008.

> The starter kit supports Visual Studio
>   2008 SP1 on 32 bit or 64 bit Windows
>   Server 2008, Windows Server 2003,
>   Windows XP, and Windows Vista. The
>   starter kit uses RSS feeds, which are
>   supported on Internet Explorer 7 or
>   later. Using Internet Explorer 6 is
>   not recommended. If you are using IIS
>   to publish your Web site or Web
>   application, it is recommended to use
>   IIS 7. The starter kit will
>   successfully install on Visual Studio
>   2008 Express Editions, however its
>   full feature set may not be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, instead of using the REST Starter kit, you might want to check out the lastest bits from the [WCF Community site](http://wcf.codeplex.com).  The starter kit gets you part way there, and is sufficient for very simple things, but (from personal experience) isn't all that great for much beyond that.

The bits I mentioned above run on top of the REST support in WCF but make the entire development process a lot cleaner and add a lot of needed query standardization.